# Javascript Slider Button

Tags: javascript, slider

I am working on Javascript Image slider. I would like to understand the below code because here the `var i= image.length` and same `var i` are taking in for loop command. I am confused on how it works.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var slider_content = document.getElementById('box');

    var image = ['a','b', 'c', 'd','e'];

    var i = image.length;


    // function for next slide 

    function nextImage() {
        if (i<image.length) {
            i= i+1;
        } else {
            i = 1;
        }
        slider_content.innerHTML = "<img src="+image[i-1]+".jpg>";
    }


    // function for prew slide

    function prewImage(){

        if (i<image.length+1 && i>1) {
            i= i-1;
        } else {
            i = image.length;
        }
        slider_content.innerHTML = "<img src="+image[i-1]+".jpg>";

    }
```

Comment: I don't really see a loop in there, 'i' would be a variable just like any other. It's a perfectly normal variable name. If you explain more clearly what exactly you don't understand in the code, I will try my best to explain it.

Comment: `var i=something` declares the `i` variable. It can be used for everything. `for` loops often have a 'counter' variable, and it is often named `i`, but this means nothing: `for` can use any other variable names instead of `i`, while `i` can be used for every purpose instead of reserved for `for`.

Comment: actually i am trying to build the image slider with the help of html css and javascript without using any js library and bootstrap. This code is working fine. But i am unable to understand how that function for next slide and prew slide is working

Answer (score 1):

The code is simple and does not indeed have a for loop as Ashkan has said. I will try to explain the code according to my understanding. 
At the beginning where

```
var i = image.length
```

,the code gets the length of Image which is always 5 for your case.

When the next function is called,

```
function nextImage() {
  //When the next image function is called, the code first checks that the value i is not
  //equal or greater than image.length, since we cannot really increment i to be greater 
  //than the available images.

        if (i<image.length) {
  //Our current index is either 1, 2, 3, or 4 so we can set our current index to 5 and 
  //show image 5

            i= i+1;
        } else {
  //Our index is 5 so we have to set our index to 1. 
  //We cannot increment because we dont have image 6 or more

            i = 1;
        }
  //Show image at current index. Seems like your images are starting from Image 0 to 
  // image 4 so we subtract one.

        slider_content.innerHTML = "<img src="+image[i-1]+".jpg>";
    }
```

When the previous image function is called,

```
function prewImage(){
  //When the previous image function is called, the code first checks that the value i is not
  //less than image.length and that our current index is greater than 1.

        if (i<image.length+1 && i>1) {
  //Our current index is equal or greater than 2 so we can set it to a value just below
  //it. Notice this can never be 1 since 1-1 = 0 which is not a valid index
            i= i-1;
        } else {
  //Current index is 1
  //If the current index is 1, set it to the length of the images which is also the index
  // of the last image, that is 5.
            i = image.length;
        }
  //Show image at current index. Seems like your images are starting from Image 0 to 
  // image 4 so we subtract one.
        slider_content.innerHTML = "<img src="+image[i-1]+".jpg>";

    }
```

Hope this helps, thanks.